# How to retrieve IM message from lync client 2013 communication

Tags: c#, lync, lync-2013, lync-client-sdk

I am using lync 2013 sdk and i need to create a task with conversation IM message on the end of call.

I want some method as - `conversation.getIMmessage()` etc.

how can i implement that.

Comment: You would stand a better chance of getting an answer if you share with us what you've tried so far. e.g. have you looked at the samples in the SDK?

Comment: yes, I have tried to retrieve message with **InstantMessageReceived** event. But I want to fetch old IM message or History.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So assuming  you are using the Lync Client SDK you are going to need to add an event handler for IM received to the IM modality of each participant in a conversation.  This is best considered in reverse order:-

Set up an event handler for participant being added to a conversation:-

```
Conversation.ParticipantAdded += Conversation_ParticipantAdded;
```

In that event handler get the IM Modality for that participant, with something like:-

```
var imModality = Conversation.Participants.Single(p => p.Contact.Uri.Equals(newParticipantSIP, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).Modalities[ModalityTypes.InstantMessage] as InstantMessageModality;
```

And then add a IM received event handler to the modality:-

```
imModality.InstantMessageReceived += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    DoStuff(e.Text);
                };
```

Comment: Using this I will get current messages. How can I get some old history messages? But Thanks a lot, I have tried it.now I have to fetch **IM History**.

Comment: you could record all conversations and save or dump the content as appropriate.

Comment: I was thinking for same thing. Thanks a lot. That really helped me.