# Edit MS Lync conversation chat in java

Tags: java, lync, lync-2013, ucwa

I am launching MS lync chat  from an web application by using

```
<a href="im:<sip:someone@domain.com>">Go</a>
```

How can i set conversation title in java?

**Update :**
How can i capture the text event?  I want to retrieve chat for some other processing.
Similar to this [How to retrieve IM message from lync client 2013 communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25263573/how-to-retrieve-im-message-from-lync-client-2013-communication?rq=1)

On some event like closing the chat window, I want to save the chat in db.

**Update 1 :**
Something like this. They are in .net
https://github.com/PhilippeRaemy/LyncLog
https://github.com/bujocek/LyncIMLocalHistory

Comment: what do you mean by "text event". Would you like to get full text of the chat? I hope it's not possible - this would be terrible security breach

Answer (score 0):

This feature was removed in 2013.
See thread in https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3b4c851f-f510-4613-a750-9d3bad9bfe36/how-to-change-the-conversation-subject-in-lync-2013?forum=communicatorsdk